# Connection refused to Firebase database

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

This is the code I'm trying to run to connect to my database. I don't fully get the way to connect so I'm sure I'm making a big mistake here, or I'm missing something important:

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let cors = require("cors");
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");
let logger = require("morgan");
let helmet = require("helmet");
var firebase = require("firebase-admin");
require("firebase/database")

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
logger("tiny");
app.use(helmet());

const serviceAccount = require("./keys.json");

let config = {
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<MY_APP>.firebasedatabase.app",
};


firebase.initializeApp(config);

let db = firebase.database();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    db.ref().once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val())
    })
})

app.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log("Listened on port 5000!");
});
```

when I go to `localhost:5000` I get the error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and I wonder what it is that I a missing

Comment: Thanks for that update, I'm going to clean up my previous comments and recommend you do the same now that they're addressed. It sounds like the problem is on the connection coming *into* this code, rather than the connection from this code to Firebase. If that is indeed the case, you should be able to reproduce the same problem without including anything about Firebase. Doing so allows you to isolate the problem, and hopefully solve it yourself, or otherwise attract help from people with the right knowledge.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did as you said and removed all firebase related code and replaced it for a simple hello world express app and it works fine. With firebase, the app crashed and I get `[1]    29520 segmentation fault (core dumped)  node server/app.js` in the console